# Function that accepts a hash key and returns multiple values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a practice question that asks me to create a group_by_owners function that

"Accepts a hash containing the file owner name for each file name.

Returns a hash containing an array of file names for each owner name, in any order.

For example, for hash

```
{'Input.txt' => 'Randy', 'Code.py' => 'Stan', 'Output.txt' => 'Randy'}
```

the `group_by_owners` method should return

```
{'Randy' => ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt']`, `'Stan' => ['Code.py']}
```

So far, I could not get anything to pass. I expect that i am supposed to take in a hash so I implemented a new `files = {}` has and put in the appropriate values. But all I get is a syntax error

```
module FileOwners
  def self.group_by_owners(files)
    files = {}
    files['Randy'] << 'Input.txt' << 'Output.txt'
    files['Stan'] << 'Code.py'
  end
end


puts FileOwners.group_by_owner(files)
```

I have tried other practices  including

```
module FileOwners
  def self.group_by_owners(files)
    files = {
      'Randy' => 'Input.txt',
      'Randy' => 'Output.txt'
      'Stan' => 'Code.py'
    }
  end
end


puts FileOwners.group_by_owners(files['Randy'])
```

But I am still met with errors. I'm completely stuck. I'm obviously fairly new to Ruby, so bear with me. Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is: method ***accepts*** the hash, you do not have to build a hash, you just pass it to method. Your method has to just work with the argument passed.

When I was staring coding I was thinking the same way as you are now ;)

```
def group_by_owners(files)
  better_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  files.each_with_object(better_hash) {|(k, v), hash| hash[v] << k}
end

group_by_owners({'Input.txt' => 'Randy', 'Code.py' => 'Stan', 'Output.txt' => 'Randy'})
#=> {"Randy"=>["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan"=>["Code.py"]}
```

Comment: very helpful. Thanks!